# AppleScript is throwing a stack overflow error on changing file extension

Tags: stack, applescript, overflow

Why does this function throw a stack overflow error?

```
on convertFileExtenstion(parentFolder, thisFile)
  set filePath to ((parentFolder as text) & thisFile) as alias
  if my fileExists(filePath) is equal to true then
     set name extension of filePath to "txt"
     log filePath
  end if

end convertFileExtenstion

on fileExists(theFile)
  set fileExists to false
  tell application "Finder"
      if exists (file theFile as alias) then
          set fileExists to true
      end if
  end tell

  return fileExists
end fileExists
```

The file is just on my desktop, I am only trying to change the extension on one file.

path: `Macintosh HD:Users:xxxxxxxxx:Desktop:prebidServerBidders:client.yaml`

Edit: It's not just extensions, I can't change the file name either.

Comment: Probably some weird interaction between AppleScript and `Scripting Additions`, since you didn't specify what would be setting `name extension`.

Comment: PruitIgoe, RE: "Why does this function throw a stack overflow error?" -- You post just the _code_ of two _handlers_ and you want us to troubleshoot it? Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **and** [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then please edit your question to conform, so we can help troubleshoot the issue you are having. Thanks.

Comment: Your `fileExists()` handler is superfluous as you're coercing your `filePath` to `alias`, which can only point to paths that already exist.  If it doesn't, it throws an error.  This isn't the reason for the overflow, just something I think you weren't aware of.

Answer (score -2):

You can't set the name extension of a file this way.
the 'name extension' is a property from 'file information' you can GET but not SET.

```
 get name extension of (info for filePath)
```

- extract the file name without extension,
- add yours
- change the whole the name with the help of the Finder

`tell application "Finder" to set name of filePath to theNewFileNameWithMyExt`